# Bootstrap jQuery UI positioned to float to the top

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I've installed [Datepicker for Bootstrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and its working nicely. But I can't figure out how to use the `place` method to position the datepicker above the element instead of below. I'm guessing it works similiar to the [bootstrap popovers](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers), but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place function just auto places the date picker under your input box. Its not a function that lets you select where you want to place it.

However you can easily override the default functionality of that function with your own custom placement.

Here is an example of that http://jsfiddle.net/G7sWL/19/

All i did copy the original function and add an additional vertical offset of 10 and horizontal offset of 50.

```
$(function() {
    var picker = $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    var widget = picker.data('datepicker');
    widget.place = function(){  //the original place function
        var offset = this.component ? this.component.offset() : this.element.offset();
        this.picker.css({
            top: offset.top + this.height + 10,  // change #1 = added "+10"
            left: offset.left +50                // change #2 = added "+50"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Very nice work and thank you for taking the time to do it. I very much appreciate it. :)

Comment: I just noticed this downvote in my reputation and have no recollection of this question or answer and why I would have downvoted it. It won't let me undo my downvote unless it is edited. If you care to do so I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

From the page:

> ### .datepicker('place')
>
> Updates the date picker's position relative to the element

It only says it updates the position of the picker (which is absolutely positioned on the page), not that you can change its placement.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not elaborating. I've read the documentation but I'm not sure how to use it, there are no examples. Although, didn't know it was referring to the absolute position of it. Any ideas of how to use it, I've tried everything I can think of...Thanks again.

Comment: Just `$('#dp').datepicker('place')` on an existing datepicker input should do it, but, like I said, all it will do is update the position.